# Updating custom module

Tags: 7

I created custom module and I installed it on "Add Module" page. I've got that module in sites/all/modules. I changed that module (I went to that location and I recoded it). What should I do to update that module. It seems to me that only after recoding that module Drupal doesn't notice changes.

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you edit an installed and enabled module, Drupal will not notice you added new hooks, since the list of the hooks implemented by a module is cached from Drupal. In order to make Drupal notice you edited the module and added new hooks, you need to disable and re-enable the module, without uninstalling it.

The reason why this is necessary is that [module_implements()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_implements/7), the function that returns `TRUE` when a module implements a hook, contains the following code.

```
  // Fetch implementations from cache.
  if (empty($implementations)) {
    $implementations = cache_get('module_implements', 'cache_bootstrap');
    if ($implementations === FALSE) {
      $implementations = array();
    }
    else {
      $implementations = $implementations->data;
    }
  }
```